# Send Raw Email using AWS SES Direct API V2

Tags: c#, .net, email, mime, amazon-ses

I'm new to AWS and I'm trying to send raw email using AWS SES via Direct API v2 in .Net C#. I went through the documentation and the information was not much clear. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-raw.html

What I need to do is how to pass the MIME formatted data to the API and how to use the Authorization keys in Direct API (without using SDK).

Comment: Maybe I am just not familiar with this - but I've been using SES from C#, including raw emails - and I've never seen the concept of Direct API; let alone v2. The link in your question doesn't say anything about Direct API, either! Could you please elaborate

Comment: @Felix Hi Felix, Did you use ses using the SDK?. In the below links they mentioned that direct API is doable. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-formatted.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference-V2/API_SendEmail.html

Comment: Oh, I see! I suppose *directly* means by sending POST request to SES endpoint, as opposed to invoking APIs through SDK. No, I was always using SDK. Thank you for this clarification!