# How to connect to a specific endpoint with V2 of AWS SES API?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-net

I have some code that creates and sends email through AWS SES. I've introduced some changes, and would like to test them locally, and I found [aws-ses-mock](https://github.com/askrella/aws-ses-mock), however I'm lost as to how I'm supposed to tell my client, using V2 API and .NET SDK, that its endpoint is meant to be `localhost:8081` instead of one of the set regional providers. Any clues?

Comment: You can't send a message to a client if the client never failed.  The best way is to check the URL before a connection is made and verify that 8081 is part of the URL.

Comment: @jdweng sorry, I do not understand your message, I'm a noob. It seems to me that you left left some stuff implied that would help me understand. When I'm saying client, I refer to `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceV2Client`.

Comment: You are making an http connection from client to server.  You send from client an HTTP Request and server returns HTTP Response.   If connection never completed (used 8080 instead of 8081), the server cannot send an error message back to the client.  The error message has to be handled in the client.

Comment: Where is it stated that by default it connects to port 8080?

Comment: You are correct 80 is the default (It is in a RFC).  8080 is often used as an alternate.

Comment: No, what I mean is: where is it stated that this class by default maps to localhost at port 8080 instead of something else (like, one of the AWS SES endpoints)?

Comment: You have three parts to the URL 1) The base URL 2) The Route (after the base) 3) The Port number.  Not sure what you mean by endpoint.  Usually the endpoint is the base URL.

Comment: What I mean is that, as per my original question, from what I can tell the urls it uses as endpoints are hardcoded and I can only chose among the set of `EndpointProvider`; I was wondering how to do so.
Your reply seems to state that it goes to `localhost:8080` by default. Where is this stated?

Comment: @dhanushka-rukshan I saw that you've asked a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70487340/send-raw-email-using-aws-ses-direct-api-v2
Did you have any success, and do you know the answer to my question (or else, how did you test your code)?

Comment: Port 80 is the default as specified by the RFC specification.   It is in the TCP Header.  HTTP uses TCP for the transport layer.  The server and client need to specify the same port number like localhost:8081 when port 80 is not used as the default.